Install an old Python2.4 on a new ubuntu machine with virtualenv
I have to migrate a very old Python2.4 based application to a new Linux Server (Ubuntu with Python 3.12.3 and virtualenv 20.25.0+ installed).
On the old machine there is a Python2.4 installation created with virtualenv 16.4.
I tried:
virtualenv venv-py24 --python=python2.4

This throws the following error:
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2.4'

Is there someting, I am missing?
Regards

--python does  not manage Python installations for you, such as by installing a missing version. It only specifies which previously installed version to use. You are responsible (either manually, or by using a tool like pyenv) for making sure some python2.4 is available before creating the virtual environment.

Ah, okay.
So this means, I have to install Python 2.4 first - parallel to my current Python3 installation ?
